# Using links in switch statments PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, switch-statement

Hello I'm trying to learn switch statements and I am having trouble linking to my other php files with a switch statement my code it:
Main file:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="NavMenu">
<a href="index.php?page=Home"> HOME </a>
<a href="index.php?page=Gallery"> GALLERY </a>
<?php
$var1 = "DieRoller";
$var2 = "MISC TOOLS";
$type = "list";
?>
<select name="<?php echo $type;?>" id="<?php echo $type;?>">
<option value="1"><?php echo $var2;?></option>
<option>
 <a href="index.php?page=DieRoller"><?php echo $var1;?></a>
</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Index File:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    require_once('includes/NavMenu.php');
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
    exit;



    <div id= "DynamicContent">
    $page = $_REQUEST['page'] ?? "null";
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
    switch ($_GET['id']) {
        case 'HOME': echo "home"; break;
        case 'GALLERY': echo "index.php?page=DieRoller.php"; break;
        default: ...;
      }
?>
```

I'm trying to get it to where when I click on the DieRoller in my main file it will redirect me to my DieRoller.php file if you have any question for me please ask

Comment: your `switch` statement should compare the `option value` in `$_GET['id']` like `1`,  but you are comparing it with `string`. Besides, which of the `$_GET` that you want to use? `page` or `id`?

Comment: I'm trying to use page

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot errors on it.
fist a html tag on without close the php.
tag <a inside  <option , doesn't work for sure.
your switch expect 1 or 2 and you put page or Gallery instead.
first you should decide what you want really do if you want just go to another page when you click the link try something like.

<a href=mylink
if you you want set parameter before send it  u need put a form surround the selector and a submit button in the end.